# Intel Compiler vs GCC code generation differences

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, intel

I'm learning about x64 programming and the differences between Intel C++ compiler and GCC and how they optimise the instructions

Questions:

1. What's the best way to tell Intel Compiler to dump the assembly code (similar to gcc -S) ?
   Right now I debug and disassemble in Visual Studio to see the instructions.
2. the disassembled Intel compiled psum1 doesn't obey the convention of argument passing on register rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9   like what can be seen in GCC assembler output. What am I missing here?
3. for some reason, intel compiler doesn't optimize away memory access, what settings do i need to change?

   ```
               //intel compiler /Ox output
               p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
               000000013F79118B  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rcx+rax*4+8]
               000000013F791191  addss       xmm0,dword ptr [rcx+rax*4+4]
               000000013F791197  movss       dword ptr [rdx+rax*4+4],xmm0
               000000013F79119D  addss       xmm0,xmm1
               000000013F7911A1  movss       dword ptr [rdx+rax*4+8],xmm0

   //GCC -O3 ouput
   LBB1_3:
   decq    %rdx
   LBB1_2:
   addq    $4, %rsi
           addq    $4, %rdi
           addss   (%rdi), %xmm0
           movss   %xmm0, (%rsi)
   testq   %rdx, %rdx
           jne LBB1_3
           LBB1_4:
   ```

### Original C code

```
void psum1( float a[], float p[], long int n ) {
    long int i;
    p[0] = a[0];
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
    }
}
```

### Disassembly from Intel C++ Compiler 2013 on Visual Studio 2010:

- Full optimisation /Ox
- Enable Intrinsic function /Oi
- Favor speed /Ot

  void psum1( float a[], float p[], long int n ) {
      long int i;

  ```
  p[0] = a[0];
  000000013F791156  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [rcx]
  000000013F79115A  mov         dword ptr [rdx],eax

  for( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
      000000013F79115C  jle         psum1+7Ah (13F7911CAh)
      000000013F79115E  mov         eax,1
      000000013F791163  lea         r10d,[r8-1]
      000000013F791167  mov         r11d,r10d
      000000013F79116A  xor         r9d,r9d
      000000013F79116D  shr         r11d,1Fh
      000000013F791171  lea         r8d,[r11+r8-1]
      000000013F791176  sar         r8d,1
      000000013F791179  test        r8d,r8d
      000000013F79117C  jbe         psum1+5Eh (13F7911AEh)

      p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
      000000013F79117E  lea         eax,[r9+r9]

      for( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
          000000013F791182  inc         r9d

          p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
          000000013F791185  movsxd      rax,eax

          for( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
              000000013F791188  cmp         r9d,r8d

              p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
              000000013F79118B  movss       xmm1,dword ptr [rcx+rax*4+8]
              000000013F791191  addss       xmm0,dword ptr [rcx+rax*4+4]
              000000013F791197  movss       dword ptr [rdx+rax*4+4],xmm0
              000000013F79119D  addss       xmm0,xmm1
              000000013F7911A1  movss       dword ptr [rdx+rax*4+8],xmm0

              for( i=1; i<n; i++ ) {
                  000000013F7911A7  jb          psum1+2Eh (13F79117Eh)
                  000000013F7911A9  lea         eax,[r9+r9+1]
                  000000013F7911AE  lea         r8d,[rax-1]
                  000000013F7911B2  cmp         r10d,r8d
                  000000013F7911B5  jbe         psum1+7Ah (13F7911CAh)

                  p[i] = p[i-1] + a[i];
                  000000013F7911B7  movsxd      rax,eax
                  000000013F7911BA  movss       xmm0,dword ptr [rdx+rax*4-4]
                  000000013F7911C0  addss       xmm0,dword ptr [rcx+rax*4]
                  000000013F7911C5  movss       dword ptr [rdx+rax*4],xmm0
              }
          }
          000000013F7911CA  ret
          000000013F7911CB  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]
  ```

### GCC Assembly output with full optimisation -O3

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.globl  _psum1
.align  4, 0x90
_psum1:
Leh_func_begin1:
pushq   %rbp
        Ltmp0:
movq    %rsp, %rbp
        Ltmp1:
movss   (%rdi), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm0, (%rsi)
cmpq    $2, %rdx
        jl  LBB1_4
        addq    $-2, %rdx
        jmp LBB1_2
.align  4, 0x90
LBB1_3:
decq    %rdx
LBB1_2:
addq    $4, %rsi
        addq    $4, %rdi
        addss   (%rdi), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm0, (%rsi)
testq   %rdx, %rdx
        jne LBB1_3
LBB1_4:
popq    %rbp
        ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

Comment: Hint: with GCC run `gcc -O3 -mtune=native -fverbose-asm -S`

Comment: thanks i'll have to try more gcc switches